# Hexapod walking algorithm

Tags: legged, hexapod, walk, gait

I am making a hexapod project with my friend. There is a issue about its walking style. Generally tripod gait is formed as two steps: first move legs 1,3,5, then 2,4,6 which corresponds to moving one leg from one side and two legs from other side but the legs are located circular instead side by side. So, this situation makes us wondering if it would rotate or not instead of moving forward when the 
tripod gait is implemented.

Our robot's legs are like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPdRUbJcNzM

What kind of walking algorithm is suitable for that kind of robot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter whether the legs are mounted in a circle or not. You should be using [inverse kinematics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics) to place the tip of each foot on the ground.

If you know the dimensions of your robot and share the hexagon arm is attached you can account for the joint offset in your calculations. After that, there is some geometry involved to solve for the angles.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms14494.pdf) paper might help decide what sort of walking algorithm suits your purpose.